# How to add a link (inside Mantis) to a note/comment?

Tags: mantis

Creating a link to an issue in Mantis is done via the hash symbol # followed by the issue number.

- Example: #123

How do I link to a note?

Comment: This feature is annoying to me. Can I turn that off? It should be off by default IMO.

Comment: don't know if you can turn it off. in case not, you could use `$g_bugnote_link_tag` to customize it to something else than the default `~`.

Comment: Yes I changed it, I think to false or something, or ### etc, I think it works so far.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the `~` symbol, i.e `~42` to link to the bugnote with the id `42`. The prefix is configurable using the `$g_bugnote_link_tag` setting.

A little clarification, if needed, taken from [here](http://mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18945): the `~` notation works a little different according to MantisBT version. In 1.1.x shows only the NoteID (e.g., 0026006), but since 1.2.x and above, the link was changed to IssueID:NoteID (e.g., 0009261:0026006).

Comment: Is there a way to link to an attachment/image from the note?

Comment: @AgnelKurian you can simply copy/paste the link from the "Attached Files" section, but I don't think there's a way to quick link like the # or ~. There'a also some html support by default under $g_html_valid_tags. And of course plugins which may do this.

Comment: @scipilot, If I copy and paste links, and later I have to move my Mantis installation to a new server or directory, the links become invalid.

Answer (score 16):

Form this : http://inform7.com/mantis/view.php?id=259 :

```
 Also for future reference: you can link to another issue by prefixing
 the issue number with #, or link to a comment by prefixing the comment
 number with ~.


 # 259 (without the space) => 0000259
 ~ 559 (without the space) => 0000259:0000559
```

Comment: Is there actual documentation on this? It would be nice if you didn't have to search the bugtracker's bugtracker to discover the syntax of your bugtracker. :s

Comment: @tkh Yes, there is a cheatsheet: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet